# R shiny app issue while loading an xlsx file

Tags: r, shiny

[image]I am stuck up with one issue in R Shiny app where I am uploading an xlsx file which has data present in 8 different sheets. I did the bind_rows for all the 8 sheets and I am able to append everything into one dataframe. The issue is I am not able to see the output when I execute the Shiny app. The error I am seeing is "Error : path must be a string". Could you please help me in resolving this issue. Thank you beforehand for the clarification.

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(

# Application title
titlePanel("SDV Complaince Report"),

# Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
        fileInput("file1", "Choose Excel File",
                  multiple = FALSE,
                  accept = c(".xls",
                             ".xlsx"))
    ),
    
    # Show a table of the final output
    mainPanel(
        tableOutput("contents")
    )
)
```

)

```
# Define server logic required
server <- function(input, output) {

output$contents <- renderTable({
    fname <- input$file1
    sheet <- excel_sheets(fname$datapath)
    data_frame <- lapply(setNames(sheet, sheet), 
                        function(x) read_excel(fname, sheet=x, col_names = F))
    for(i in 1:length(data_frame)) {
        data_frame[[i]]$...5 <- as.numeric(data_frame[[i]]$...5)
        print(class(data_frame[[i]]$...5))
    }
    
    # attaching all dataframes together
    data_frame <- bind_rows(data_frame, .id="Sheet")
    
  
})
```

}

```
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: in the ```lapply()```, you use ```fname```, instead of ```fname$datapath```. Maybe switching it would help?

Comment: The issue still persists despite changing it. I am getting the issue at this section as per the log file.   sheet <- excel_sheets(fname$datapath)
Error in : `path` must be a string

Comment: Hmm... outside of of shiny, does the function within the ```renderTable()``` work for your excel file? When I've copied your code but modified the ```lapply()``` from ```fname``` to  ```fname$datapath```, using my own test data set, it seems to work for me, outside of formatting oddly.

Comment: yes, the function is running fine outside the Shiny app for my excel file. I just attached the error that I am seeing in the post. Please let me know if I am missing anything here.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not adding anything different than the suggestion I had in the comments, but to be able to show the whole file I needed the answer space for more info. There are three differences between my code and the one you original posted. One, I blocked off `library(tidyverse)` since it's not used in this example. Two, I added `req(input$file1)` to the table, to prevent it from trying to load the table before a file has been selected. And three, the most important change, is changing `fname` to `fname$datapath` in the `read_excel` portion of `lapply`.

When you try the code I have below on your dataset, does this work? It works for me on my own test data set. If it doesn't work for you, then my only guess is your dataset is causing the issue. Best of luck!

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
# library(tidyverse) #Not needed for the test
library(dplyr)

# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("SDV Complaince Report"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose Excel File",
                multiple = FALSE,
                accept = c(".xls",
                           ".xlsx"))
    ),
    
    # Show a table of the final output
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    req(input$file1) #Requiring prevents the error in this table as it tries to load before file selected
    fname <- input$file1
    sheet <- excel_sheets(fname$datapath)
    data_frame <- lapply(setNames(sheet, sheet), 
                         function(x) read_excel(fname$datapath, sheet=x, col_names = F)) #Most important change - fname to fname$datapath
    for(i in 1:length(data_frame)) {
      data_frame[[i]]$...5 <- as.numeric(data_frame[[i]]$...5)
      print(class(data_frame[[i]]$...5))
    }
    
    # attaching all dataframes together
    data_frame <- bind_rows(data_frame, .id="Sheet")
    
    
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This has worked now.. I think adding the req(input$file1) as well helped in resolving the issue. Thank you so much for sharing the resolution..